# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on generated JavaScript file by TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` when I run my app.
I'm writing in TypeScript and compiling to *ES5* .

**TypeScript file**

```
// Holds all windows
private windows!: [string,BrowserWindow][];

/**
 * Creates a browser window and returns it.
 * Note: The window will auto .show() when returned
 * 
 * @param windowView View name to be loaded
 * @param windowOptions BrowserWindow options 
 */
public createWindow(windowView:string, windowOptions?:BrowserWindowConstructorOptions): BrowserWindow {

    // Instantiates the BrowserWindow
    let window = new BrowserWindow(windowOptions)

    // Loads the view into the BrowserWindow
    window.loadFile(this.VIEWS_PATH + '/' + windowView + this.VIEWS_EXTENSION)

    // Adds view and window to BrowserWindow tupple array for futher use
    this.windows.push([windowView, window])

    // Closes and deletes this specific BrowserWindow from the BrowserWindow tupple array
    window.on('close', (event) => {
      console.log('deleted', event.sender.id)
      this.deleteWindow(undefined, event.sender.id)
    })

    return window
}
```

**JavaScipt file generate by TypeScript**

```
/**
 * Creates a browser window and returns it.
 * Note: The window will auto .show() when returned
 *
 * @param windowView View name to be loaded
 * @param windowOptions BrowserWindow options
 */
createWindow(windowView, windowOptions) {
    // Instantiates the BrowserWindow
    let window = new electron_1.BrowserWindow(windowOptions);
    // Loads the view into the BrowserWindow
    window.loadFile(this.VIEWS_PATH + '/' + windowView + this.VIEWS_EXTENSION);
    // Adds view and window to BrowserWindow tupple array for futher use
    this.windows.push([windowView, window]);
    // Closes and deletes this specific BrowserWindow from the BrowserWindow tupple array
    window.on('close', (event) => {
        console.log('deleted', event.sender.id);
        this.deleteWindow(undefined, event.sender.id);
    });
    return window;
}
```

TypeScript isn't defining the windows tupple array on JavaScript file, is it because it isn't initialized on TypeScript file? Any workaround?

Many thanks.

Comment: try `private windows!: [string,BrowserWindow][]=[];`

Comment: Change `this.windows.push([windowView, window])` to `this.window.push([windowView, window])` .... Remove the `s` so it should be `this.window`

Comment: @jonathanHeindl that worked! :D Go ahead and aswner to the question on the main thread :)

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I only had to initialise the tupple array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `private windows!: [string,BrowserWindow][]=[];` 
(:P)